# Syncfusion WPF SfDatagrid GridImageColumn width

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I added a GridImageColumn to my grid and am adding an image to it.  It seems that the width of the column (when I set the ColumnSizer="Auto") is being set to the length of the url I am dl'ing the image from, and not the actual image size.  If I use some really short url, the column's width is also really small.

Is this expected?  Do I need to just explicitly set the width of the column?  What I want is for the column to automatically be the width of the widest image in the column.

Here is the grid:

```
<syncfusion:SfDataGrid  x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}" ColumnSizer="Auto">
                <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                    <syncfusion:GridImageColumn
                        MappingName="TEST"
                        HeaderText="TEST"
                        Stretch="None"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        ValueBinding="{Binding Path=ImagePath, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverter}}" />
                </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
            </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
```

Here is StringToImageConverter.  It just fetches the BitmapImage and returns it:

```
class StringToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const string UriPrefix = "https://www.someprefix.com";

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string imageName = value is string ? UriPrefix + value : string.Empty;
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And it comes out looking like this (the image has a width of 112 and the url is pretty long, basically as wide as the column is in the below screenshot):

[image: Column is wide]

Answer (score 0):

We are unable to reproduce the reported sizing issue with GridImageColumn when the ColumnSizer as Auto. We have attached the sample which we have tested at our end in version 16.3.0.21 and you can find that from the below link

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/215737/ze/GridDropDownAndReadOnlyColumns27872867.zip

If you still can reproduce the issue, then could you please revert us with the modified sample for reproducing the reported issue at our end, thereby we could analyze and provide you with the appropriate solution at the earliest.

Regards,
Deivaselvan

Note: I'm working for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thanks.  I can reproduce the issue using your example.  To reproduce, replace the orderInfo.ImageLink properties with @"https://ffrk.denagames.com/dff/static/lang/image/sphere_material/131008300/131008300_112.png" and in StringToImageConverter replace UriKind.Relative with UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute.  I am on Syncfusion 16.2.0.50.